# Applying border image in IE 10; CSS3 Pie does not work

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am trying to use this image as a border around a div.

[image: Red border image]

I want it to stretch around the div like a rubber band. This is the CSS I am using.

```
div#divname {
 border-image: url('red-border-box.png') 30 30 30 30;
 behavior: url('/wp-content/uploads/scripts/PIE.php');
}
```

It works in IE 11 and the latest Chrome and Firefox. I tried using CSS3 Pie for IE 10, but there's no effect.

Is there an alternative approach I can use for IE 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Border-image` is [not supported by IE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image). You may need to try something like this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnSK2/1/)

```
div {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsCre.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well for most viewport widths, but for the narrower ones, the right and left borders are too thick. border-image does a pretty good job of rendering the thickness to look good. What do you think can be done with your solution?

Comment: That's tricky. You would probably need to slice up the image into multiple images so you have more control over each side. But that could get tricky since the borders overlap.

Comment: Perhaps I should conditionally use this styling only for IE 10 and border-image for the rest?

Comment: Yes, using this as a fallback would definitely be a great idea.

Comment: To target specific IE browsers, I suggest checking out http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ie-media-block-tests.php